# How to add hardcoded values for an Employee class

Tags: c#

I would like to know what is the syntax for declaring an Employee class with multiple hard coded records

```
Employee objEmployee = new Employee() {Name="Sumanth",Id=101,Salary=5000.00 };
```

The above code is for single record.

What is the syntax for creating multiple records?

**EDIT**

I would like to know what are the ways I can create multiple records along with /without the List. When I use List, I can get features like IEnumerable, IQueryable etc.

Comment: You add multiple lines, one for each record...or you create a collection object (such as a List to contain them all) and add each record to that collection, perhaps with list and object initializer syntax.

Comment: Use a `List<Employee>` maybe.

Comment: you should google the following , `C# Basics Tutorial` and focus on the section dealing with `Instance and Classes, and Object Initialization`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways but primarily what you need is a  create a collection here.

One of the simplest is to create a `List<Employee>` using object initializer this way :

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
{
   new Employee() {Name="Sumanth",Id=101,Salary=5000.00 },
   new Employee() {Name="Ehsan",Id=102,Salary=6000.00 },
   //........................ and so on
}
```

Now you can add multiple employee objects in the list to hold in memory and then later can access those from the `List<T>`.

You can loop on them to get each employee back later in program where you need to retrieve them like:

```
foreach(var employee in employees)
{
   // do something here
}
```

Comment: Could you please remove your answer for this so that I can delete my question also. Due to this question, I am barred from posting new questions. Please bear with me.